# Where should I apply some sorting function for folders and subfolders in Python code?

Tags: python, sorting, directory, subdirectory

Dear all I need your help. Could you be so kind and explain to me when (on which stage) should I write code part which will sort my folders and subfolders?

On the images, you can see my folder&subdfolders structure: [image: folders][image: subfolders].

I want all my folders and subfolders to have a normal ascending style for integers, '1', '2', ..., '10', '11', ...

I thought to put some code to the part:

```
zoom_levels = [i for i in sorted(range(zoom_min, zoom + 1), key=int)]
folders_for_xtiles = [k for k in sorted(range(0, 2 ** zoom), key=int)]
for zoom_level, folder_for_xtile in itertools.product(zoom_levels, folders_for_xtiles):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_to_tiles_folder, str(zoom_level), str(folder_for_xtile)))
```

but it did not work.

Then I was thinking to put a sorting function when I dig into my folders with a code, but I do not know what kind of methods I need to apply from os module?:

```
for zoom_level in range(zoom_min, zoom + 1):
    xtile_path = os.path.join(path_to_tiles_folder, str(zoom_level))
    for xtile_number in range(0, 2 ** zoom):
        ytile_path = os.path.join(xtile_path, str(xtile_number))
```

Thank you all

Comment: Are you only observing the folders in your IDE, or do you have some internal code that reads them in some order? I don't know that Python can do anything to change the order your IDE shows the folders in (it probably does it's own sorting). You may or may not be able to control the order other code reads the files (it depends on the file system).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanations it may work actually. Yes, I am observing such order of my folders in Pycharm IDE. Maybe it only concerns IDE, because when I open this structure via normal folder opening in Windows it is shown sorted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most OSs don't make strong guarantees about the order you'll see files within a folder. Some filesystems might have a predictable order (such as sorting by date of creation), but since most OSs support multiple different filesystems (which might have different orders) that doesn't help all that much. Instead, it's usually up to each client program that's reading the file names to sort them itself, if it cares about the order they're in. Many low-level programs do not care about order, so this is probably a reasonable choice for the OS designers (who don't want to impose the overhead of sorting the filenames when it's not needed).

So, the issue you're having is not actually a problem with your Python code. Rather, it's an issue with your IDE that you probably won't be able to change. It sorts the folders you've created lexicographically, which means that `10` comes before `2`, just like `ba` comes before `c` in alphabetical order. Unless your IDE has some features to change its sorting method (which seems unlikely), you probably can't fix that directly.

The file manager provided by your OS may sort differently (and give more options for how to sort). Many programs use what's called a "natural sort" for filenames. That separates the names into numeric and non-numeric parts, then uses each as a separate step of the sorting (with corresponding numeric parts sorted by number, rather than lexicographically). If you were writing your own code to display the folders, you might need to replicate that, but in the current situation it doesn't seem like it's necessary.

What might help you though is to zero-pad the names. Rather than creating folders named `1` and `2`, create `01` and `02`. Then a naive sort will put `10` after `09` instead of putting it between `1` and `2`. Here's how you can change your folder creation logic to work with zero-padded numbers:

```
zoom_levels = [i for i in range(zoom_min, zoom + 1)]
folders_for_xtiles = [k for k in range(0, 2 ** zoom]
for zoom_level, folder_for_xtile in itertools.product(zoom_levels, folders_for_xtiles):
    os.makedirs(os.path.join(path_to_tiles_folder,
                             format(zoom_level, '02'),
                             format(folder_for_xtile, '02')))
```

The main change is to use `format` instead of `str` to turn the numbers into strings. I pass the `02` formatting code to tell Python to pad the numbers to two digits with leading zeros. Note that I removed the `sorted` calls from the list comprehensions, since they weren't doing anything (`range` already produces results in ascending order, not that it really matters for our purposes).

The last code block you show suggests that when you access the folders, you're doing so by recreating the names directly by number, rather than by browsing the folders and asking the OS for the names that appear in each. If you're doing that, you don't need to care about the order the folders were created in (or what order they appear in when viewed in another program). If you generate the numbers in order, then you'll access the folders in order too. It doesn't matter what order the filesystem would provide, since you're not asking the filesystem about what folders there are, since you know their names ahead of time.

Comment: thank you so much for your detailed, explicit and understandable answer! I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 1):

This seems like more like a OS behavior rather than Python behavior. Try padding the folder names 1 through 9 with a zero. For example:

```
for zoom_level in range(zoom_min, zoom + 1):
    xtile_path = os.path.join(path_to_tiles_folder, str(zoom_level))
    for xtile_number in range(0, 2 ** zoom):
        xtile_folder_name = str(xtile_number).zfill(2) if len(str(xtile_number)) == 1 else str(xtile_number)
        ytile_path = os.path.join(xtile_path, xtile_folder_name)
```